# Overlay map tiles, only display those within rectangle bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API 3 to draw a grid over several United States. After kludging together my own solution which involved iteratively drawing over 62 thousand polylines, I found that it was far easier and less intensive to simply tune Google's [Overlay Map Type example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-overlay) to the grid size I need, where the side length of each square at zoom level 20 is equivalent to 90 feet. This functions well so far.

My problems now are twofold:

1. I need to only draw the squares that fall within the bounds of a fixed rectangular polygon. The whole satellite map should be drawn, but I only need the grid overlay within this area. Partial overlaps *should* be drawn.
2. I also need the numbers that appear at the top left of each grid square to begin counting from the upper left of this rectangle. This means that at zoom level 20, the length of each coordinate should be no more than 5 digits, as the maximum X value would be ~45300 and the maximum Y value would be ~16800. Currently, the squares start counting from 90° N 180° W and have six-digit coordinates at zoom level 20.

I suspect the solution involves checking each grid square's coordinates with [poly.containsLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) (and probably running this on zoom_changed), but Google's example page does not adequately explain how to access the individual grid squares, so I don't have any method of checking them.

How do I access these grid squares? Or do I need to make a new OverlayView?

My code so far follows.

```
var map;

function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
}

CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = coord;
    div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
    div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
    div.style.fontSize = '10';
    div.style.color = '#FFFFFF';
    div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
    div.style.borderColor = '#FFFFFF';
    return div;
};

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 38.2711991, lng: -82.6292357},
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
});

map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(233, 233)));

gridBox();
}

function gridBox(){
    var gridBox = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.638, -75.387),
        new google.maps.LatLng(36.497, -75.387),
        new google.maps.LatLng(36.497, -89.539),
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.638, -89.539),
    ];
    gridBoxSet = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: gridBox,
        geodesic: false,
        strokeColor: "#AAAAAA",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
        fillOpacity: 0.2
    });
    gridBoxSet.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing how the getTile method was writing the coordinate values to the innerHTML of each div, I figured out how to limit which ones were drawn. Here's my code. It's pretty hackish and doesn't directly check the tiles against the bounds, but it works and performance-wise it's very smooth.

```
var map;
var zoom;

function CoordMapType() {
    this.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(233, 233);
}

var firstX = 289496; //coord.x of top left of rectangle
var firstY = 433476; //coord.y of top left of rectangle
var lastX = 45290; //width of rectangle in tiles
var lastY = 16959; //height of rectangle in tiles

CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    var coordX = coord.x-(firstX/(Math.pow(2,(20-zoom))));
    var coordY = coord.y-(firstY/(Math.pow(2,(20-zoom))));
    var maxX = lastX/(Math.pow(2,(20-zoom)));
    var maxY = lastY/(Math.pow(2,(20-zoom)));
    var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "("+coordX.toFixed(0)+","+coordY.toFixed(0)+")";
    div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
    div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
    div.style.fontSize = '10';
    div.style.color = '#FFFFFF';
    div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
    div.style.borderColor = '#FFFFFF';
    if((coordX>-1 && coordX<maxX) && (coordY>-1 && coordY<maxY)){
        return div;
    } else{
        return null;
    }
};

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 38.2711991, lng: -82.6292357},
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });
    map.setTilt(0);

    map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
        zoom = map.getZoom();
        console.log(zoom);
    });

    drawGrid();

    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView) provides an OverlayView class for creating your own custom overlays. The OverlayView is a base class that provides several methods you must implement when creating your overlays. The class also provides a few methods that make it possible to translate between screen coordinates and locations on the map.

Add a custom overlay

Here is a summary of the steps required to create a custom overlay:

- Set your custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance of `google.maps.OverlayView()`. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class.
- Create a constructor for your custom overlay, and set any initialization parameters.
- Implement an `onAdd()` method within your prototype, and attach the overlay to the map. `OverlayView.onAdd()` will be called when the map is ready for the overlay to be attached.
- Implement a draw() method within your prototype, and handle the visual display of your object. `OverlayView.draw()` will be called when the object is first displayed.
- You should also implement an `onRemove()` method to clean up any elements you added within the overlay.

You can also see the full, working example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Comment: This isn't exactly helpful. By quoting the documentation at me, you mean to suggest that I create a new Custom Overlay, yes? I've worked through the Custom Overlay example, and it's not close to what I need, particularly in terms of performance and displaying the coordinates of a tile. What I need is tile functionality limited to the bounds of a polygon.